# Calculate new Column using date

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

I'm starting with spotfire, I have a dataconector which contains the following columns, I would like to create a new column which indicates if an object found in an 'LSTOR' device is found at a later date in
another device other than 'LSTOR'.

Thanks for your help

| TimeStamp | Equipement | Object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/09/2021 | LSTOR | A |
| 11/09/2021 | MUN3 | C |
| 14/09/2021 | MUN3 | F |
| 12/09/2021 | MUN3 | A |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it for your sample dataset defining first a column LSTOR_TS as:

```
case  when [Equipement]='LSTOR' then Min([TimeStamp]) over ([Object]) end
```

then defining the target column as:

```
SN(case  when Max([LSTOR_TS]) over ([Object])<Max([TimeStamp]) over ([Object]) then True else False end,False)
```

the SN(..) being there to cater when there is no LSTOR value.

This solution would return False if there were LSTOR and another equipment on the same day.

Comment: great, can you please accept the answer?